# How to generate a SHA-256 hash in base64 format from commandline?

Tags: bash, base64, sha-2

How do I generate a SHA-256 hash in base64 format from commandline? I want a piped commands kind of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following piped command:

```
printf InputKey | sha256sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xxd -r -p | base64
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution is using `openssl` and a bit shorter:

```
echo -n InputKey | openssl sha256 -binary | base64 -
```